# What is the proper method for blending beers?

Tags: fermentation

In regards to [this question](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/5597/salvaging-flat-beer) I've been inspired to take my flat beer and blend it with a new beer. My main question is when is the best time to combine the two beers? Should it be done at the start of primary fermentation or much later? Are there any "gotchas" or non-obvious things to keep in mind during this process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the past I have blended at Packaging time (for me this means kegging).  This has had good results for me in the past.  This also will ensure that you when you blend you can blend to taste versus blending blindly and not knowing what you'll end up with.  I believe this matches major commercial practices as well.

Comment: say one beer uses a yeast with greater attenuation than the yeast used in the other beer. Wouldn't you run the risk of over-carbonating/bottle-bombs if one yeast begins to ferment sugars left by the other yeast?

Comment: @awithrow  It depends on why the attenuation was lower, for one thing, but that is something that Geueze makers have to contend with.   The important thing is to know how much fermentable sugar is left over, and how your flora/fauna will react.

Comment: If you are bottling I would probably suggest going to a secondary to let things settle a bit anyway before going to bottling for the reason you specify.  Baka is also correct, knowing if you've hit attenuation and what fermentable sugars are left is probably the best way to avoid bombs.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing how your beer is in bottles, the best bet is to blend in the glass.  Mix the beer with good carbed beer or commercial beer.
All in all blending bad beer with good beer just makes....more bad beer.