# I added sugar and bottled the beer...aged and no carbonation

Tags: fermentation

We made the beer, it fermented fine, then waited to bottle (maybe too long afterwards) added sugar and bottled.    After waiting for the required time opened a bottle only to find it flat. Can we add more yeast and still save this batch of beer or do we need to start over...? Can the original brew be salvaged?

Comment: how long did you wait before bottling?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/4673/beer-not-carbonating

Comment: How much priming sugar did you add/mix when bottling?

Comment: Where was your beer stored?  It is the yeast that produce C02, and if they are frozen they won't be doin' much

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this question can be answered without more information:

- what was the final gravity?
- how much priming sugar did you add?
- what was 'the required time'?

Probably the best advice is wait another week or two and then sample it again. I often find it can take several weeks after bottling for appropriate carbonation.

Answer (score 0):

For best results, you should add priming sugar to a bottling bucket rather than to each bottle.  Dissolve your sugar in hot water, then rack on top of it.  Gently stir the beer for a few seconds to mix it.  DO NOT AERATE.

A good rule of thumb for carbonating in bottles is to let them sit at 70-75F for 3 weeks.

Comment: Useful information, but doesn't answer the question as to whether the user's batch of beer can be saved.

Comment: I disagree, for easy results add sugar to bottling bucket (I do it this way), for excellent priming results add sugar directly to each bottle (a lot of work). When adding sugar to bottling bucket, it may not mix properly with the entire batch making some bottles uncarbonated and some over carbonated,

Comment: http://www.brewersfriend.com/beer-priming-calculator/

Comment: @DavidPGB - I keg and only bottle a few bombers for gifts, etc. and I find [priming tablets](http://www.austinhomebrew.com/Beer/Other-Sugars/Brewers-Best-Conditioning-Tabs.html#.U005zfldUQE) to be really handy.